# programming arduino in pure c

Tags: avr, avrdude, avr-gcc, avr-toolchain

I'm trying to flash pure c-code to arduino Mega2560 board from linux using avr-gcc & avrdude. Compilation is done , now trying to flash using avr-dude, getting error as "*avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00*"

I used below command to produce hex file

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000UL led.c -o led.elf
```

*In file included from led.c:3:0:
/usr/lib/avr/include/util/delay.h:95:3: warning: #warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from  won't work as designed" [-Wcpp]
 # warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from  won't work as designed"*

And then

```
avr-objcopy -j .text -O ihex led.elf led.hex
```

finally for flashing

```
avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA2560 -P /dev/ttyACM3 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex
```

FYI: port is correct & RX pin is blinking i.e connection is perfect between computer & board

Comment: One note: `-DF_CPU=1000000UL` is 1MHz. I'm pretty sure Arduino Mega2560 runs on 16MHz. Anyway, you can try to use PlatformIO CLI (I'm using it on Linux machine and it works fine with several different Arduinos)

Comment: @KIIV , even @ 16Mhz , same probelm. any idea how to do without PlatformIO CLI?

Comment: Try prefixing your `avrdude` command with `stty -F /dev/ttyACM3 hupcl &&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In file included from led.c:3:0:
>   /usr/lib/avr/include/util/delay.h:95:3: warning: #warning "Compiler
>   optimizations disabled; functions from won't work as designed"

You should start by fixing this. Simply add `-Os` to the compiler
command line. This means “optimize for size”, and is the standard
optimization option used with Arduinos.

> avr-objcopy -j .text -O ihex led.elf led.hex

If your copy of avrdude was compiled with libelf (like the one supplied
with Ubuntu is), you don't need this: you can hand your elf file
directly to avrdude.

> avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA2560 -P /dev/ttyACM3 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex

`-F` tells avrdude to **not** verify the device signature. `-V` tells it
to **not** verify the upload. I wouldn't use any of these options unless
I had a very good reason to do so. `-c arduino` is wrong: it selects the
upload protocol used by optiboot (used, e.g., in the Uno). The
Mega 2560 uses a different bootloader based on the “wiring”
protocol. I would also add the `-D` option (disable auto erase) because
I saw the Arduino IDE using it, and because without this option I get
the error:

```
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): command failed
```

In the end, the upload command ends up being something like:

```
avrdude -p atmega2560 -c wiring -P /dev/ttyACM3 -b 115200 -D -U led.elf
```

Comment: thanks ! it is working. your explanation is clear. I'm new to avr, can you please direct me where to learn all those? @Edgar Bonet

Comment: @sankar: I don't have a good reference handy for that. I learned it the hard way, by looking at how the Arduino IDE and [Sudar Muthu's Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) do it, and by reading the man page of avrdude.